# Can't load local video with React

Tags: reactjs, path, html5-video, local

I can't load a local video with React. I've put the video in my folder "app/assets/video/concert.mp4". In my React file "search_bar.jsx", I have an HTML5 video tag I've sourced the video as:

`render(){
    return (<video src="../../app/assets/videos/concert.mp4" controls />);
}`

Here is my file structure:

- MusicianHub

  - app

    - assets

      - videos

        - concert.mp4
  - frontend

    - components

      - search_bar.jsx

The video tag works if you load an external video. Here is my webpack.config.js

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=video:src'
    }, {
      test: /\.mp4$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=video/mp4'
    }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: can you post your webpack config? Also, try doing `import video from '../../app/assets/videos/convert.mp4` and do `<video src={video} />` that way webpack recognizes it has to pull in the video file

Comment: Using webpack-dev-server huh?

Comment: @erichardson30 I've uploaded my webpack.config and included the import statement, but it looks like webpack is unhappy with the loader I provided: ERROR in Loader /Users/briantsai/Desktop/MusicianHub/node_modules/url/url.js?limit=10000&mimetype=video/mp4 didn't return a function
 @ ./frontend/components/search_bar.jsx 15:15-61

Comment: I've loaded the url-loader and file-loader modules from webpack, so the error disappeared, but now in Chrome dev tools it says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://localhost:3000/a740242064c86421e8ff988502f202a8.mp4

Comment: I think it should be `url-loader` and not just `url`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a fix for me.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6822#issuecomment-483079845

You can use src/react-app-env.d.ts to test it out:

```
declare module '*.mp4' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

Comment: This is when you use TypeScript. But yes this fixes the issue of importing videos

Answer (score 2):

This works for local file:

```
import videos from '../../app/assets/videos/concert.mp4'

render(){
return (
 <video loop autoPlay>
      <source src={videos} type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
); }
```

Comment: what if the  local path is not previously known ? ( or inside a map ? )

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go with uploading the video to Cloudinary, a remote source instead. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for local photos and videos:

```
import concert from '../../assets/videos/concert.mp4'

render(){
return (
 <video controls>
      <source src={concert} type="video/mp4"/>
      Your browser doesn't support HTML video.
 </video>
); }
```